# bootstrap adminlte 2.3.3 sidebar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, adminlte

I would like to link to http://google.com
I use admin panel AdminLTE 2.3.3, but click through to the point lessons are not going on the menu.

```
<li class="treeview">
      <a href="http://google.com">
        <i class="fa fa-pie-chart"></i>
        <span>Lessons</span>
        <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
      </a>
      <ul class="treeview-menu">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Lessons1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Lessons2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "are not going on the menu"? 
I am not sure I understood your problem...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<li class="treeview">
  <a href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-pie-chart"></i>
    <span>Lessons</span>
    <span class="pull-right-container">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
    </span>
  </a>
  <ul class="treeview-menu">
    <li><a href="http://google.com"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Lessons1</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://google.com"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Lessons2</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```